# wordpress .htaccess rewrite loop with prev domain redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 1 hosting with root htaccess for redirect to a specific folder for a specific domain
works perfect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /folder1/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /folder2/$1 [L]
```

on `folder1` i have a wp folder with wordpress installation

on `www/folder1/wp/.htaccess` i have

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /wp/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

if i go `http://domain1.com/wp/` everethings works perfect

BUT if i dont´t put the last slash `http://domain1.com/wp` and leave just the folder gets in a redirect loop.

Can someone help me please

Thanks

Comment: Luis, read the help on how to format Qs, especially inserting  code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your WP rules do not handle the `^$` condition.  I suspect that your hosting provider has a default `DirectoryIndex`.  It doesn't really matter what this is, say it matches to `index.html`, then on a subrequest wp:rule2 will convert this to `wp/index.php` -- a case of two wrongs accidentally making a right.  But this all goes wrong in the case of wp, because in this case %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is a directory.

The safest thing to do here is to explicitly handle the ^$ case by adding the rule

```
RewriteRule ^$    index.php [L]
```

as rule 2 to the `wp/.htaccess`.